# I'm confused about "some way"

Tags: grammar

> A)Everyone has arrived here in some way.
>
> B)Everyone has arrived here in one way or another.

1)Are they natural sounding sentences?

2)Do they have the same meaning?

3)Does 'some way' mean:

- a particular way (unspecified) that all people went through

or

- All people went through several kinds of way and 'some way' just tells that people went through any of them(not all people went through the same way in this interpretation)

?

Answer (score 1):

A)Everyone has arrived here in some way.

B)Everyone has arrived here in one way or another.

Correction:

A)Everyone has arrived here some way. [**no in:** by bus, by plane, walking]

B)Everyone has arrived here one way or another. [**no in**] [by bus, by plane, walking

You arrive at a place by walking there, running there, taking a means of transportation.

Way would refer to the method of transportation used to get to the place.

A) What way did you get here?
B) I took the bus.

Answer (score 0):

They both sound natural, and mean the same thing.

> > 3)Does 'some way' mean:
>
> a particular way (unspecified) that all people went through or
>
> All people went through several kinds of way and 'some way' just tells
>   that people went through any of them(not all people went through the
>   same way in this interpretation)

The 2nd option is correct. "**Not all people went through the same way.**"

"A particular way (unspecified)" would be a *missing* 3rd sentence:

> C) Everyone has arrived here in one way.